# django-notifs raising an exception: django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Notification has no field named 'timestamp'

Tags: python, json, django, notifications, migration

I'm trying to apply Notifications system to my django (version 3.2) app for  the first time using the tutorial: https://django-notifs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#

I'm stuck at the installation process. First I solved the `(fields.E180) SQLite does not support JSONFields.`, using the documentation at: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/JSON1Extension

After running makemigrations, it worked fine. BUT after running `manage.py migrate`, it threw the following error:

`raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name)) django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Notification has no field named 'timestamp'`.

Please help me out :(

A part of a full very long traceback (cannot embed images due to cruddy reputation):

File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\DJANGO\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 126
, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\DJANGO\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py",
line 240, in database_forwards
from_field = from_model._meta.get_field(self.name)
File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\DJANGO\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 610, in g
et_field
raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Notification has no field named 'timestamp'

Comment: The migrations could be half applied after the failure? Can you drop the entire DB and try migrating again so it's fresh?

Comment: You mean delete ? Ok I'll do it.

Comment: Yeah, delete the db. Can you paste the full traceback? Is that field supposed to exist on that model?

Comment: No it didn't solve anything :(

Comment: Pretty sure that field doesn't exist on that model. where is it being referenced? Full traceback might help

Comment: Ok I'll do it right away